# How to append a word to a specific string with double quotes in it?

Tags: c#, regex, string, append

I've got a string with multiple words with double quotes & a string to append. I need to append a string to the double quote where .xyz is present. Let say for example:

```
string stringToAppend = "append";
string str = "Lorem Ipsum is \"simply\" dummy text of the \"printing.xyz\" and typesetting industry";
```

I need to append to the start of that particular double quote where the string ".xyz" is present.

The current output is:

> Lorem Ipsum is "simply" dummy text of the "printing.xyz" and typesetting industry

I want it to append & print like :

> Lorem Ipsum is "simply" dummy text of the "appendprinting.xyz" and typesetting industry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this code using regular expressions:

```
string stringToAppend = "append";
string str = "Lorem Ipsum is \"simply\" dummy text of the \"printing.xyz\" and typesetting industry";

// I used index of a match to insert string, added one because pattern also matched "
str = str.Insert(Regex.Match(str, "\"\\w+\\.xyz").Index + 1, stringToAppend);
```

I used pattern `"\w+\.xyz`.

`"` - match `"` literally

`\w+` - match one or more word character

`\.xyz` - match `.xyz` literally

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var extension = ".xyz";
var data = "Lorem Ipsum is \"simply\" dummy text of the \"printing.xyz\" and typesetting industry";
var insertion = "append";
int index = data.IndexOf(extension);
for(int i = index; i > 0; i--){
 if(data[i] == '\"'){
  return data.Insert(i, insertion);
 }
}
```